# Свойства strong retain и прочее в objective-c

Tags: ipad, objective-c, xcode, ios, iphone

Коаеугольный камень! Я понимаю что наверное тема изъезженная вдоль и поперек!
Но тем не менее!

В каких случаях retain, readonly, readwrite, copy, assign, strong?

начитал массу материала, еще массу нашел - но каша в голове только гуще стала по этому вопросу (

Выручайте!

Может есть ссылка на доступное описание, может здесь просветите!

Answer (score 1):

Да там в общем-то все в названиях есть:

retain - когда необходимо получить ссылку на объект и не освобождать его пока он нужен, strong почти то же, но для ARC

readonly - свойство только для чтения, часто оно не привязано к конкретному полю, а динамически генерится в геттере

assign - когда надо иметь ссылку, но не надо контролировать время жизни объекта, обычно это делегаты, после введения арк заменено на weak главный плюс которого автосброс в нил при освобождении объекта

copy - при присвоении делается копия объекта т.е. созлается новый объект с теми же параметрами, а не просто сохраняется ссылка